# Difference between cp and mv force overwrite?

Tags: linux

have a bit of a problem with cp and mv overwrite in my script. 
as far as I get it both commands can be forced:

```
cp -f
mv -f
```

but here is were the problem starts. cp -f still calls to approve the overwrite and I know why: because in the .bashrc it is set cp='cp -i'.... so it is aliased, so either command cp -f, or \cp -f, of unalias for the session and so on....

but my confusion is why is not mv acting the same. in my .bashrc mv is also mv='mv -i' but I can force a mv command with a mv-f....

I would like to keep all the setting and in my script run the commands like \cp -f or \mv -f (less headache in the future) but would like to know why cp and mv are not acting the same???

thanks

Comment: IIRC .bashrc is not read when processing scripts ("non-interactive shell" mode) specifically to avoid this kind of problem. So it's not likely that your setting in bashrc is really causing this; have you verified? i.e. comment it out and try again. Also, post more information; the script and the exact contents of .bashrc

Comment: @davmac thanks for suggestion, glad I know now that .bashrc is not read when processing scripts.I am getting this behavior and difference between cp and mv in terminal.

Comment: You need to make your questions specific, and not make assumptions. If you see this on the command line and not actually in a script then you should edit your question appropriately. FWIW I think this is just an inconsistency between the way `cp` and `mv` handle/process their arguments; they are different programs, after all. You could try filing a bug against GNU coreutils if it bothers you.

Comment: @davmac thanks, I sorry if i was not specific enough. Will try to improve on that the next time. No no, it does not bother me at all just wanted to make sense of it, so it would not lead to some mistakes later on.